# Как изучить язык самому?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пробую читать книгу Марка Лутца, но чем дальше читаю, тем больше у меня вопросов и никакой практики

Answer (score 2):

Для каждого человека обучение идёт в индивидуальном формате. Нет определенной схемы обучения. Марк Лутц идёт в уклон в ООП, чтобы успешно вникнуть в главы этой книги нужна минимальная база. Для самостоятельного изучения того или иного языка нужно иметь минимум несколько источников информации (к примеру если питон, то это книги того же Лутца, bite of python и проекты Эйлера для практики). Для решения своих вопросов вам необходима лишь поисковая система, не более. После изучения базы изучаешь алгоритмы по книгам, фреймворки в зависимости от деятельности и всё смежное с твоими целями (Например: для специалиста питона в сферах веб это сокеты и сети, базы данных MySQL, django, flask и тд.)

PS Исходя из правил сайта рекомендую не задавать вопросы не технического характера или же вопросы, ответы которых явно можно найти в открытом доступе.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую